# How do I get form elements with multiple values to display only one/single field with the add more button?

Tags: webforms

I expect what I'm asking is supposed to be the default behavior of form elements where users can input multiple values, however when I have a form element that has 3 or more allowed input values, a minimum of 3 input fields always display in the form. If 2 values are allowed then both show in the form and of course the 'add more' button does not. I have tried all the possible combinations under Advanced > Multiple Settings and no combination produces the desired result of having only one input field displayed with the 'Add More' button visible to load additional fields. Something to note is that if I set the 'Number of add more items' to a value that is equal to or greater than the 'Allowed number of values'(v) minus 3 I get an error notification in the form saying "*Add {button_name} more items must be lower than or equal to n*' (where n = v - 3 OR 1 if v ≤ 3).

I have looked through all the form settings and cannot see any option that would change this behavior. I have googled and only found the standard answers regarding the multiple settings options. I'd be grateful if someone could point me in the right direction.

Drupal 10 | Webform 6.2.0

Form YAML:

```
accreditations_list:
  '#type': textfield
  '#title': 'Accreditations List'
  '#multiple': 10
  '#multiple__min_items': 0
  '#multiple__empty_items': 0
  '#multiple__sorting': false
  '#multiple__add': false
  '#multiple__remove': false
  '#multiple__add_more_input': false
```

Output:
[image: Webform_img]

Comment: Please share the YAML of a small form that does this.

Comment: I've added the YML and output screen grab to my original question. Thank you for responding.